# How to implement horizontal view android studio

Tags: android, css, android-studio

im trying to implement an android aplication when your activity, cointains 3 or more 'main windows' like in the image -> 'A'. 'B'.'C'. so how is posible make when you slide you touch screen change from A, to B, for example, i was thinkin in a horizontal view, and inside of each item use a relative layout, but im not sure, its my first time with this kind of problem, thanks.

[image]

Comment: ViewPager is what u need :) You can get hundreds of tutorials on it :) or you can see official docs :) http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html. Here is one such tutorial https://dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using . I checked it overall looks pretty good for someone learning it for first time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using android `ViewPager`. Each `ImageView` would be inside a `Fragment` that would reside inside your `Activity`. Check out this [example](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/android-tutorial-using-the-viewpager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use Tabbed Activity template when you want to make this type of `Activity`. `ViewPager`, `Adapter` and `tab layout` will be automatically implemented for you. Just make small changes in your `Adapter` according to your needs and use one `Fragment` for one tab and you can create as many tabs as you want in an `Activity`.
If you want i will post an example of an `Adapter` as i just implemented an `Activity` with 3 tabs.
To get your basics strong on `ViewPager`, `tab layout` and `Fragment` sections adapter read out [this](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) link.